# How to strip the newline when use sharing clipboard

Tags: shell, vim

*description updated*

I want to share clipboard between VIM and shell so that when I have text selected in VIM, I can use `SHIFT+INSTERT` in shell to paste it in command line. One of the user case is to grep certain word in current directory.

I am using VIM version 7.4, and have following line added in vimrc file:

```
set clipboard=unnamedplus
```

This approach works fine when do yank in normal mode. When I select text by `CTRL+v` in VIM, SHIFT+INSERT in shell always paste a newline along with the word.

Is there any way to stripe the newline?

Comment: Also try `:vimgrep /{pattern}/[g][j] {file} ...`. This is especially useful if you want to search the word under the cursor, since you can ctrl-r_ctrl-w insert it into the commandline, that is you type ":vimgrep /ctrl-r_ctrl-w/ **/*".

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann thank you for the tip. I am aware of this solution and actually use vimgrep in daily work. But it doens't solve my issue listed in question.

Comment: `CTRL+v` should not select a newline, if you only select a horizontal string (why not `v` instead, btw?). What's the output of `:reg "+` - does it have a newline (`^M`) at the end? If not, blame `SHIFT+INSERT`.

Comment: @VanLaser In VIM, copy & paste via register works well, output of `:reg "+` has no newline. I guess you're right, `SHIFT+INSERT` is the one to blame. However, I don't know how to deal with it ...